# Creating two vectors from pair of points

Tags: c++, vector

In my code I have a following template

```
template <typename T> struct VectorXY {

    std::vector<T> x;
    std::vector<T> y;
};
```

In another cpp file I am creating pair of x and y points as shown below (This is an example and not an actual code. This is created in a for loop):
`xy_points = ((x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3))`
and so on.

Now I want to extract all the x values like x1, x2, x3 etc. and store them in the x_vector as shown above in the template. Similarly I want to do it for y values like y1,y2,y3 and store them in the y_vector.

**Edit**:

```
template <typename T> 
static Point2D<T>::VectorXY<T> create_x_y_vectors(const std::vector<Point2D<T>> point_vector)
{

    VectorXY<T> xy_vec;

    std::vector<std::pair<T, T>> xy_points(point_vector.size());    

    for (size_t i = 0; i < point_vector.size(); ++i) {

        xy_points[i] = std::make_pair(point_vector[i].x(), point_vector[i].y());

        // This is still incomplete. Hence there is no return value.

    }
```

Unfortunately, I cannot share the Point2D class here but what this function does is as explained above, creates points like:
((x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)) etc..

I would like to now extract x1, x2, x3 points and store them in x_vector
in the template and similarly do it for y1, y2 and y3.

And here is where I am clueless. How do I go about storing x and y values in their respective vectors? Also, I want to return xy_vec from the function.

Thank you. I need your help.

Comment: Show your code where you are creating pointers and an object of vectors.

Comment: it is not clear what is your problem. You know how to add elements to a `std::vector` in general? Maybe you can show the code you have an issue with, or code you would like to write, but cannot get it working?

Comment: Yes using push_back we can append the values to a vector.

Comment: I have edit the code and copied the function @idclev463035818

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something in this manner:

```cpp
for (auto point: xv_vec) // Assuming point type is small {
    x.push_back(point.x);
    y.push_back(point.y);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by small?

Comment: Usually, that it does not contain memory allocations. In this case I suppose that the size of T should be at most 8 bytes.

Comment: Umm, Yes This class is used for int and double so it is at most 8 bytes.

Comment: So in my case (code in the question) i do not need to make pairs of x,y values?

Answer (score 1):

In the for-loop where you are creating your 2D points, why not add the `x`-values immediately to xv_vec using

```
xv_vec.x.push_back(x_value);
```

and the y values in a similar fashion?

Comment: I have edited the question and copied my function which makes pairs of points. How can I iterate through xy_points and store all x values in the x_vector? Can we avoid using push_back in the for loop? Sorry if this is a dumb question.